# How to Airseal and Insulate Texas Homes

Tags: insulation, air-conditioning, energy-efficiency, air-quality, air-sealing

I am interested in what I can do to help improve the energy efficiency of older Texas homes.

I am looking to purchase one in the new year but it is my understanding that in 2012 the energy efficiency code standards where implemented and home efficiency became significantly better. So for homes older than 2013 what are the most cost effective energy improvements?

From looking at government websites it seems that the two most effective ways to get efficiency and other benefits are:

1. Air Barriers - Low Air Changes per Hour(ACH)
2. Insulated Attics - Energy department claims up to 30% efficiency improvement having air handlers and equipment inside the conditioned envelope.

What are cost effective ways of retrofitting these features into older homes if possible.

Comment: air handler is always inside

Comment: the biggest source of energy loos are the windows (single pane)

Comment: What is the scope of work you're looking at? For instance, the cost-effectiveness of over-roofing changes significantly if re-shingling is required anyway vs. if you're doing a stand-alone energy retrofit...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I do not have a particular scope of work in mind. I am open to long term returns so pay back in 10 years on energy savings. Beyond that it is not worth it unless it adds some other feature like sound management, insect management, air cleanliness or other features. I recognize the question is open but I am trying to find something that improves the returns as my old house 3100sqft would have three months of 750/month energy bills. I felt that was way too high.

Comment: This may depend on climate, but here in the Northeast air-sealing is the single highest payback in improving the energy efficiency of most older houses (keep the conditioned air longer rather than having to heat/cool new air from outside) with attic insulation being second. Check whether your utility companies sponsor free on-site energy efficiency evaluations;  those may come with discounts or rebates on recommended work, and sometimes some free bulbs or smart power strips or whatever so even if you don't take their advice you come out ahead.